# Saving a variable to an INDIRECT variable

Tags: excel, vba

In the example below, variable X creates indirect variables T1, T2, etc. as N is incremented from 1 to 4

X = “T” & N

For each value of N, I want to save  another variable to each indirectly referenced variable T1, T2, etc.

I’ve tried using the vba INDIRECT function, but without success. Can anyone help?

Indirect(X) = my stored variable

For example, I want to end up saving the referenced variables as …

T1 = 123.00

T2 = 456.00

T3 = 789.00

You get the idea…

Comment: Any reason you don't use a simple array? T(1), T(2)...

Comment: The problem I’m having is accessing the variable. I’ve never used arrays. Wouldn’t you still have the basic problem?

Comment: _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Using arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: I agree: sounds like you want an array. E.g., `Dim T(4) As Single`.

Comment: @PeterConstable note that's a 5-element array unless `Option Base 1` is included.

Answer (score 2):

Simple array example

```
Dim T(1 to 4), i As Long
For i = 1 To 4
    T(i) = i * 2 'for example
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your advice on using arrays. So easy. Works great! Never used them before.